# Why am I getting the error 'exceptions.ValueError: too many values to unpack'?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following dictionary, that is a json object generated from an XHR request, where the dictionary keys are made up of tuples:

```
{(u'goal', u'corner', u'rightfoot'): 1, (u'goal', u'openplay', u'rightfoot'): 3, (u'miss', 
    u'corner', u'header'): 8, (u'goal', u'corner', u'header'): 1, (u'goal', u'openplay', u'leftfoot'): 2,
     (u'miss', u'openplay', u'rightfoot'): 30, (u'miss', u'corner', u'rightfoot'): 2, (u'miss', 
    u'crossedfreekick', u'header'): 3, (u'goal', u'penalty', u'rightfoot'): 1, (u'miss', u'fastbreak', 
    u'rightfoot'): 2, (u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'rightfoot'): 3, (u'goal', u'openplay', u'header'): 
    1, (u'goal', u'crossedfreekick', u'rightfoot'): 1, (u'miss', u'openplay', u'header'): 2, (u'goal', 
    u'crossedfreekick', u'header'): 1, (u'miss', u'openplay', u'leftfoot'): 22, (u'miss', 
    u'directfreekick', u'rightfoot'): 1, (u'miss', u'crossedfreekick', u'leftfoot'): 1}
```

I am using the following piece of code to conditionally sum values within the dictionary above:

```
goal1 = {"'goal','openplay','leftfoot'", "'goal','openplay','rightfoot'", "'goal','openplay','header'", "'goal','openplay','otherbodypart'"}
                            regex1 = sum(int(value) for key, value in regex if key in goal1)
```

However, this produces the following error message:

```
regex1 = sum(int(value) for key, value in regex if key in goal1)
    exceptions.ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is and/or correct an alternative syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex1 = sum(int(value) for key, value in regex.items() if key in goal1)
```

You need to use `dict.items` which contains the key and the value, looping over the `regex` dict you are  iterating over just the keys so you cannot unpack the key and the value hence the error.

The keys are also tuples so you need to store the keys as tuples in `goal1`:

```
goal1 = {('goal','openplay','leftfoot'), ('goal','openplay','rightfoot'), ('goal','openplay','header'), ('goal','openplay','otherbodypart')}


print(regex1)
6
```